# Comparing values in a database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was wondering how I could compare a value/varchar in my database to a string in my own PHP script. Below is a picture of my database if it helps and I just want to compare the value inside the ThunderOrNot column (ID = 1) to a string of "Thunder". Neither of my bottom 2 'if' statements work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!
[image: Picture of DB]

```
    <?php

$link = mysqli_connect('.....', '.....', '.....', '.....');

$query = "select * from thunderDemo";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
         echo $row["ThunderOrNot"];
}

if($row[ThunderOrNot] == 'Thunder')
{
         echo "The Value equals Thunder";
}

if($row == 'Thunder')
{
         echo "The Value equals Thunder";
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Quotes my friend, quotes...`$row["ThunderOrNot"]`

Comment: The only issue I have with this @PedroLobito is that PHP will try to resolve ThunderOrNot as a constant, and on finding none throws a notice and then tries to place quotes around the 'constant' itself. The warning should not stop processing the of the code, depending on how the OP's server is set up. `"E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Use of undefined constant ThunderOrNot - assumed 'ThunderOrNot' 
The Value equals Thunder"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put the `if` inside the `while` loop
2. Add quotes to `$row["ThunderOrNot"]` (not as important, because an **unquoted string** will be interpreted as a `constant` by php and, in this case,  its value will be `ThunderOrNot` (kudos:[Jay Blanchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011527/jay-blanchard)), i.e. :

---

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row["ThunderOrNot"] == 'Thunder'){
        echo "The Value equals Thunder";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you put your conditions after there are no more records returned.  Move them inside your `while` loop.

Note that you should add a second parameter to `mysqli_fetch_array()`: `MYSQLI_ASSOC` for it to return an associative array.

The condition would then be: `if ($row['ThunderOrNot'] == 'Thunder')`

Comment: [PHP already fetches an associative](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php): " Fetch a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both."

Comment: It defaults to MYSQLI_BOTH which can be confusing and slower.

Comment: Why do you argue for nothing?  Look at the code.  He loops through the records and just checks the conditions after the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
if($row["ThunderOrNot"] == 'Thunder')
```

Index is a text.